# Django static file not loaded/found

Tags: html, css, django

EDIT:
**Please, has nobody a idea what is going on? From my point of view I tried everything people posted somewhere else, but django is not finding the static folder in the root directory. I am super desperate at this point and I posted like everything related to this issue below.**

I have a small Django project and the css static files are not loaded when there are not in the `app/static/app/css` folder.

I want to use `website/website/static/css`. However, it is not working even so I follow all tutorials and other posts, but it seems that I am missing something and this something took already some hours of my time and it is killing me.

In the settings.py I have:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

and my html template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link href="{% static 'css/warenkorb.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello user!</h1>
        <p>something you want</p>
        <img src="{% static 'images/img.jpg' %}">
    </body>
</html>
```

I see it that way:
`os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` = ~/website/website/static and then I load this path in the html template and extend the rest to it like /css or /images, but nothing happens. My assumption is that for example `"{% static 'css/warenkorb.css' %}"` leads to `~/website/website/static/css/warenkorb.css`

Any advice is highly appreciated. Finding a solution is super annoying at this point, because I have no clue what is going on and no idea what else I could do.

EDIT - Directory Tree

Don't be confused as I removed some directories of the dir tree to avoid to many entries. I just kept the apps with their static folder.

The static files within the app/app/static are found. However, I want to have a central static folder (see all the way down `static/images/firmenlogo.jpg`), like with the templates folder. And no matter where I put the static folder the image within is not loaded.

```
.
├── README.md
└── website
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── home
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── home
    │   │       ├── css
    │   │       ├── images
    │   │       ├── js
    │   │       ├── mail
    │   │       └── vendor
    ├── manage.py
    ├── templates
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── home.html
    │   ├── umwelt.html
    │   └── warenkorb.html
    ├── umwelt
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── umwelt
    │   │       ├── css
    │   │       └── vendor
    ├── warenkorb
    └── website
        ├── asgi.py
        ├── db.sqlite3
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── static
        │   ├── css
        │   │   └── warenkorb.css
        │   └── images
        │       └── firmenlogo.jpg
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

EDIT:
`settings.py`

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'umwelt',
    'warenkorb',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

`main urls.py`

```
"""website URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("home.urls")),
    path("", include("umwelt.urls")),
    path("", include("warenkorb.urls")),
]
```

`warenkorb app urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.warenkorb, name="Warenkorb"),
]
```

`warenkorb.views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def warenkorb(request):
    return render(request, "warenkorb.html", {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` is not `~/project/project/static`

it is `~/project/static`

---

move the file `~/project/project/static`  to `~/project/static`

or  add `~/project/project/static`  into `STATICFILES_DIR`

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "project/static")
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your approach, however still no results. No matter where I put the static folder (except within ```app/app/static```) it is not found. I think that I miss something basic. Is ```BASE_DIR``` related to the path where the ```settings.py``` and ```wsgi.py``` are located or is the path everytime different because ```BASE_DIR``` starts somewhere in an app folder?

Answer (score 0):

Change your SETTINGS TO SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Also check the main urls.py file and add this lines of codes in it

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

### ADD THIS AFTER YOUR urlpatterns
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

```
YOUR TREE STRUCTURE SHOULD BE LIKE THIS, FIX IT AND IT SHOULD WORK NORMALLY, NOTICE THE WAY THE STATIC FOLDER IS, OKAY

.
├── README.md
└── website
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── home
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── home
    │   │       ├── css
    │   │       ├── images
    │   │       ├── js
    │   │       ├── mail
    │   │       └── vendor
    ├── manage.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── warenkorb.css
    │   └── images
    │       └── firmenlogo.jpg
    ├── templates
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── home.html
    │   ├── umwelt.html
    │   └── warenkorb.html
    ├── umwelt
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── umwelt
    │   │       ├── css
    │   │       └── vendor
    ├── warenkorb
    └── website
        ├── asgi.py
        ├── db.sqlite3
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        | 
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Let me know if this works if not tell me the new improvement so i can direct you further

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the changed ```BASE_DIR``` causes a crash because it is of type string and not PosixPath. ```File "~/Dokumente/website/website/website/settings.py", line 75, in <module>
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'```. However. your BASE_DIR and the default one from Django result in the same path anyways ```~Dokumente/website/website```. Am I calling the static file wrong within the html template?

Comment: OHH, are you using the latest version of django

Comment: You shouls change it back to "BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent"

Comment: Yes, I am using Django version 3.1.2

Comment: Did you remember to use the command "{% load static %}" at the begining of each page

Comment: Use your link like this "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/warenkorb.css' %}" />"

Comment: ohh, i noticed something right now, it seems your static directory is not in the right place, "make sure your static folder is in the same root as manage.py files", it should work perfectly now

Comment: It is still not working. No matter if the static folder is in some dir as ```manage.py``` or in the folder with ```db.sqlite3``` and ```asgi.py``` or above the root. And I load ```{% load static %}``` at the beginning as you can see in my template above.

Comment: It is super confusing for me why django is not finding it and it is eating me up, because I have no clue. It seems to be path issue, but changing the path of the static folder to any possible path is somehow not helping :(

Comment: make the static folder in same directory as the manage.py and see if it works, also update the question with the tree image, so i can see if you did it correctly

Comment: When I call the html with my browser I get the following error in the console: ```"GET /warenkorb HTTP/1.1" 200 224
 "GET /static/images/firmenlogo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1689
```, maybe that helps, because it looks different for sites where the image is loading ```   "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 3518
"GET /static/login/images/firmenlogo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 829
```

Comment: Nice, it seems we are getting to the root of the issue. But i can see any login path on the tree structure. Have you applied any "upload_to="something"" in your models.

Comment: All my ```models.py``` for each app are empty. What do you mean by ```upload_to```?

Comment: alright, the upload_to is usuaully used in the models.py file to specify where a picture or file to be uploaded to

Comment: if all the solutions are not working still, maybe you can screenshot all the images of all of the settings.py, urls.py, you html pages as well as the tree structure so i can go through them and help you

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I added the ```settings.py``` and ```urls.py```. The directory tree and the html of the warenkorb app was already there. Please let me know when you need something more.

Comment: The problem is quite obviously, I have told you to remove the whole static folder and make it on the root directory just like the way db.sqlite, home are

Comment: You mean the way I have it changed in the dir tree from the original question? That is also not working though and I tried that already and it does not matter where I put the static folder. I put it somewhere else, restart the website and still no results :(

Comment: update your tree structure in the question, let me confirm that it is in the right order that i have suggested

Comment: I updated the directory tree. Thanks for looking over it.